# One-Time Synchronization with SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, synchronization

We are currently migrating our whole IT systems (application server, web server, DBMS etc.) to a new datacenter. The systems used before have been spread out across several datacenters in Europe and one of the goals for this migration was to have it all in one place, in one private cloud. After an initial migration of the productive systems on a particular day, we are right now reconfiguring the whole systems, going to be testing them thoroughly. Afterwards we will have to bring the newly migrated, configured and tested systems to the latest version and will use the new system.

The systems so far have been using several large SQL Server 2008 databases, transferring them to the new datacenter has been quite painful, and had to be done via harddrive, since the outgoing network connection from that old location is only 10 Mbit. So I don't want to use a brute force approach to redo the whole way through using a harddrive, so transport the whole databases, I'd rather like to use database tools to get the job done.

I've heard of several technologies applicable for this, varying from SQL Server Replication to the Sync Framework, but I would like to know which of them would be the best for a one time synchronization of such larger databases, having especially in mind the rather slow outgoing network connection and a forced disconnect every 24 hours at that old Location.

I'd still go for Sync Framework, but the more I read about it, it seems to be rather targeted for scenarios where you want to implement periodic updates between several databases, so I'm unsure if I overlooked a rather simple and easier solution for this synchronization.

Comment: I think your solutions already are efficient. Sync Framework require constant network connection, and SQL Server tools like Mirroring, Replica, etc for one-time sync is not the best. I suggest you to: backup database, compress and move to new location, then restore. Optionally you can use network for moving files, in this case avoid using upload but always download, (i.e. download the file on shared internal ftp and from new location download the file from ftp)

Comment: Thing is, the databases are rather large (35 Gigabyte), and since our initial migration, not that much data has changed, so I would like to avoid the long process of transferring the whole database once again, that is the main reason I was looking into the direction of Sync Framework 2.1

Comment: Ah ok... it's quite different...for this purpose you can use SQL Data Comparison shipped with SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272686(v=vs.103).aspx)